# How do i check if line is empty then dont show it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the part i'm using in my javascript to read the lines from a text file and add them to a jquery plugin newsticker:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://risq.github.io/jquery-advanced-news-ticker/assets/js/jquery.newsTicker.js"></script>
<style>
.newsticker {
    max-width: 620px;
    margin: auto;
}

.newsticker li {
    color: #4e4e4e;
    background: #F2F2F2;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #2c8162;
}

.newsticker li:hover {
    background: #FFF;
}
</style>
<script>
   $('body').find('.newsticker').remove();//It will clear old data if its present 
   var file = "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/test.txt";
    $.get(file, function (txt) {
            //var lines = txt.responseText.split("\n");
            var lines = txt.split("\n");
            $ul = $('<ul class="newsticker" />');
            for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
                //save(lines[i]); // not sure what this does
                $ul.append('<li>' + lines[i] + '</li>'); //here 
            }
            //$ul.appendTo('body').newsTicker({
            $ul.appendTo('div.wcustomhtml').newsTicker({
                row_height: 48,
                max_rows: 2,
                speed: 6000,
                direction: 'up',
                duration: 1000,
                autostart: 1,
                pauseOnHover: 1
            });
    });
</script>
```

The content format in the text file is like this for example:

```
Hello everyone
5/3/2014

Hi world
5/3/2013

This is a test
6/3/2012
```

I want each time to dislay two lines in the plugin jquery for exmaple this is two lines:

```
Hi world
5/3/2013
```

Then after this two lines there is empty lines space so dont display it. Then the next two lines.
So in the plugin jquery newsTicker i should see the text scrolling like this:

```
Hello everyone
5/3/2014
Hi world
5/3/2013
This is a test
6/3/2012
```

Each time two lines without the space/empty lines. 
In general it's working but it also show the empty/space lines too.

EDIT**

This is the text file content how it look like:

```
http://textuploader.com/rl0v
```

The text is in hebrew but for example this is two lines:

דיווח:ראמי מחלוף,מבכירי משטרו של אסד,עזב עם משפחתו את סוריה.מבזקים.
דווח במקור בתאריך: 07.04.14

Then there is empty line then another two lines.
And this two lines i want to display each time in the jquery newsticker and scroll them up as one block of two lines.

Comment: What is `lines` content?

Comment: Could you post raw contents of the text file?

Comment: I edited your question so that the line breaks are clear. It helps if you check to see that it is formatted the way you expect before posting.

Comment: Edited my question added the complete javascript code i'm using and also added a link to the text file content: http://textuploader.com/rl0v  And also explained what i want it to do.

Comment: And this is how it looks like now at my site: http://newsxpressmedia.com/test.html

Comment: Tried the solutions also with the IF statement it didn't work. Maybe i need to change something with the newsTicker style ? Maybe use a better visual looking jquery plugin ? The idea is to scroll up news.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing step of lines `for` loop:

```
   $('body').find('.newsticker').remove();//It will clear old data if its present 
   var file = "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/test.txt";
    $.get(file, function (txt) {
            //var lines = txt.responseText.split("\n");
            var lines = txt.split("\n");
            $ul = $('<ul class="newsticker" />');
            for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i+=3) {  // step: 3
                //save(lines[i]); // not sure what this does
                $ul.append('<li>' + lines[i] + '</li>'); //here 
                $ul.append('<li>' + lines[i+1] + '</li>');
            }
            //$ul.appendTo('body').newsTicker({
            $ul.appendTo('div.wcustomhtml').newsTicker({
                row_height: 48,
                max_rows: 2,
                speed: 6000,
                direction: 'up',
                duration: 1000,
                autostart: 1,
                pauseOnHover: 1
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

check the line's length is greather than 0 in your loop:

```
for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
     //save(lines[i]); // not sure what this does
     if (lines[i].length>0)
          $ul.append('<li>' + lines[i] + '</li>'); //here 
 }
```

Comment: wonder why it gets downvoted ... seems its the solution of this obvious problem :O

Comment: rupps i'm using now your solution in my code and still the same didn't help. look on my site: http://newsxpressmedia.com/test.html see how it looks like also look on my updates i did in the question added the full javascript code and also a link to the text file content so you can see how it look like. I don't know why your solution is not working.

Comment: can you add this in the loop: `window.console.log ("LINE "+i+" VALUE ["+lines[i]+"]");`...  maybe the lines are not empty but with spaces, if that's the case you can do: `if (lines[i].trim().length>0)` ...

Answer (score 0):

its looks as though you need to check whether the line is empty before you append it.

```
for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
    // check if an empty line
    if(lines[i] != ""){
        $ul.append('<li>' + lines[i] + '</li>'); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to show the text in single `li`, `trim` the line and check if it's not empty then add it to `text` variable, try this:

```
$.get(file, function(txt) {
    var text = '';
    var lines = txt.split("\n");
    $ul = $('<ul class="newsticker" />');
    $.each(lines, function(i, v) {
        v = $.trim(v);
        if (v !== '') {
            text += v + ' ';
        }
    });
    $ul.append('<li>' + text + '</li>');
    $ul.appendTo('div.wcustomhtml').newsTicker({
        row_height: 48,
        max_rows: 2,
        speed: 6000,
        direction: 'up',
        duration: 1000,
        autostart: 1,
        pauseOnHover: 1
    });
});
```